# How to fix 'Undefined index:' in PHP form action?

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I am working on a booking facilities on both HTML and PHP files. Whenever I tried to submit the form on my booking facilities page then after that the form will insert the data into mysql table called **booking_facilities** under mysql database called **M3_156020K_Syahri_SportFacility**. Instead, it show me this error:

> Notice:  Undefined index: activities on line 16
>       Notice:  Undefined index: venue  on line 17

**MySQL Database**

[show database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRhKl.jpg)

**BookFacilities.html**

[show website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYCYa.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bookingfacilities/bookingfacilities_desktop.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bookingfacilities/bookingfacilities_tablet.css" media="screen and (max-width:768px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bookingfacilities/bookingfacilities_mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width:480px)">
<script src="js/bookfacilitiesvalidate.js"></script>     
</head>


<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<header>

<nav id="mainMenu">
  <img src="logo/logo.png" id="logo">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="rates.html">Booking Rates</a></li>
    <li><a href="facilities.html">Recreation</a></li>
  </ul>  
</nav>

</header>


<section id="banner">

    <div id="ritu" class="shadow">
       <img src="images/content_pure.jpg">
       <img src="images/Sports-Hub-Gym.jpg">
       <img src="images/gym.jpg">
       <img src="images/ClubFitt2jpg.jpg"> 
    </div>
</section>


<section id="content">

<div id="booking">

    <div class="row">
       <div class="image" style="background-color:black; color:white; font-weight:bold;">
           <p style="padding-left:15px; padding-top:0px;">Booking Facilities</p>
       </div>


       <div class="image" style="background-color:white; color:black; font-weight:bold;">
           <p style="padding-left:15px; padding-top:0px;">Booking Cart</p>
       </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div id="box">

    <div class="user">
       <form action="facilities.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
       <p style="color:white; font-size:18px;">Activites</p> 
         <select name="activities" id="activities">
             <option value="0">Select an activity</option>
             <option value="1">Badminton</option>
             <option value="2">Basketball</option>
             <option value="3">Table Tennis</option>
             <option value="4">Running Track</option>
             <option value="5">Dancing</option>
             <option value="6">Swimming Pool</option>
             <option value="7">Soccer</option>
         </select>

        <p style="color:white; font-size:18px;">Venues</p> 
         <select name="venue" id="venue">
             <option value="0">Select a venues</option>
             <option value="1">Sports Field and Running Track</option>
             <option value="2">Tennis Courts</option>
             <option value="3">Dance / Aerobics Studios</option>
             <option value="4">Indoor Sports Hall</option>
             <option value="5">Multipurpose Rooms</option>
             <option value="6">Indoor / Outdoor Swimming Pool</option>
         </select>
      </form>

    </div>

    <div class="user">

      <form action="facilities.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
       <p style="color:white; font-size:18px;">Days</p> 
         <select name="days" id="days">
             <option value="0">All Days</option>
             <option value="1">Sun</option>
             <option value="2">Mon</option>
             <option value="3">Tues</option>
             <option value="4">Wed</option>
             <option value="5">Thurs</option>
             <option value="6">Fri</option>
             <option value="7">Sat</option>
         </select>

        <p style="color:white; font-size:18px;">Date</p> 
        <input type="date" name="calendar" id="calendar"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="searchbtn" value="Search" style="margin-top:20px;">
      </form>

    </div>

</div>


</section>


<footer>

<p>© Copyright 2016 SportLab. All Rights Reserved.</p>   
<nav id="submenu">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Sitemap &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;| </a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</a></li>
       <li><a href="term.html">Term of Use  </a></li>
       <li><a href="privacy.html">| &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Privacy </a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


</footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**facilities.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Booking Facilities</title>
</head>

<body>


<?php


if(isset($_POST["searchbtn"])) 
{
      $a=$_POST['activities']; <--- Line 16
      $v=$_POST['venue']; <--- Line 17
      $dy=$_POST['days'];
      $dt= date('d-m-y',strtotime($_POST['calendar']));

      $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" , "M3_156020K_Syahri_SportFacility");

      $sql_insert = "INSERT into booking_facilities (activities, venue, day, date) values ('$a', '$v' , '$dy' , '$dt' )";
      $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql_insert);
      if($result)
      {
          echo "Success";
      }
      else
      {
          echo "Failed";
      }
}

 ?>



</body>
</html>
```

Although day is insert into mysql table but not for activities and venues.I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.How may i fixed it?

Comment: use only one form to submit all field

Answer (score 2):

Check the following line:

```
<form action="facilities.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
       <p style="color:white; font-size:18px;">Days</p> 
         <select name="days" id="days">
             <option value="0">All Days</option>
             <option value="1">Sun</option>
             <option value="2">Mon</option>
             <option value="3">Tues</option>
             <option value="4">Wed</option>
             <option value="5">Thurs</option>
             <option value="6">Fri</option>
             <option value="7">Sat</option>
         </select>

        <p style="color:white; font-size:18px;">Date</p> 
        <input type="date" name="calendar" id="calendar"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="searchbtn" value="Search" style="margin-top:20px;">
      </form>
```

here, **searchbtn** is available in the above form and **activities** belongs to different form. With in

```
isset($_REQUEST['searchbtn'])
```

You cannot access `activities` as it belongs to different form. So remove all forms and make it one.

Answer (score 0):

Use one form to submit all fields

```
<form action="facilities.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
    <!-- select for activities -->
    <!-- select for venues -->
    <!-- select for days -->
    <!-- submit button -->
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are initializing Two Forms with same action. So when you click each form, then elements which is inside that form will be submitted. but when you are getting request, you are try to get values from both forms, So it shows you Error,

```
<form action="facilities.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
.....
</form>
```

Use this following code for your need,
HTML File

```
<div id="box">
    <form action="facilities.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
    <div class="user">
       <p style="color:white; font-size:18px;">Activites</p> 
         <select name="activities" id="activities">
             <option value="0">Select an activity</option>
             <option value="1">Badminton</option>
             <option value="2">Basketball</option>
             <option value="3">Table Tennis</option>
             <option value="4">Running Track</option>
             <option value="5">Dancing</option>
             <option value="6">Swimming Pool</option>
             <option value="7">Soccer</option>
         </select>

        <p style="color:white; font-size:18px;">Venues</p> 
         <select name="venue" id="venue">
             <option value="0">Select a venues</option>
             <option value="1">Sports Field and Running Track</option>
             <option value="2">Tennis Courts</option>
             <option value="3">Dance / Aerobics Studios</option>
             <option value="4">Indoor Sports Hall</option>
             <option value="5">Multipurpose Rooms</option>
             <option value="6">Indoor / Outdoor Swimming Pool</option>
         </select>
    </div>

    <div class="user">
       <p style="color:white; font-size:18px;">Days</p> 
         <select name="days" id="days">
             <option value="0">All Days</option>
             <option value="1">Sun</option>
             <option value="2">Mon</option>
             <option value="3">Tues</option>
             <option value="4">Wed</option>
             <option value="5">Thurs</option>
             <option value="6">Fri</option>
             <option value="7">Sat</option>
         </select>

        <p style="color:white; font-size:18px;">Date</p> 
        <input type="date" name="calendar" id="calendar"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="searchbtn" value="Search" style="margin-top:20px;">
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Use the same `facilities.php` code for the insert. Here No need of HTML Tags inside this PHP file, because your are just trying to do some back-end works using this file, then after redirect to another page with success message.